# How do you restrict parameters in R when curve fitting?

Tags: python, r, regression, curve-fitting, non-linear-regression

I am quite the newbie to R and need to fit a curve to some data points for my high school 12th grade thesis (yes, that exists).
I have a set of datapoints, which are as follows:

```
A(0.15, 0.6)
B(0.44, 1.06)
C(0.921, 1.22)
D(1.66, 1.5)
E(2.36, 1.58)
F(2.74, 1.52)
G(3.46, 1.68)
```

And I would like to model them by a function of the form y=a*log(b(x-c))+d. How would I do that? I have tried some approaches, but so far I always got the response

```
Computation failed in 'stat_smooth()': Missing value or infinity produced when evaluating the model.
```

I suspect that this is because R considers all possible values for the parameters a,b,c and d, and that b and c might thus cause some problems since the logarithm is only defined on the domain of the positive real numbers (0 excluded). Is there some way for me to solve this problem? I know that b has to be positive and non-zero, and I know that c cannot equal x. However, I don't know how to implement this.

If you don't know how to help me solve this issue in R, it would be super cool if you could just write an alternative in python or matlab because I know a bit of these two languages as well. Please just keep in mind that I have to use the Gauss-Newton algorithm.

Any support would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try these initial parameter estimates: a =  2.8E-01, b =  5.7E+02, c =  7.5E-02, d = -4.4E-01

Comment: Why do you have to use Gauss-Newton?  Can you edit your question to include the code you've tried so far that gives rise to the error?

Comment: @BenBolker I fit the posted data using the unmodified posted equation with no problem. I have a good fit, which is where the initial parameter estimates in my previous comment came from. Everything worked normally for me.

Comment: Maybe my algebra (or logic) was wrong.

Comment: @JamesPhillips, how did you get to these starting values?

Comment: @JamesPhillips did you use another algorithm (e.g trust region reflection) to approximate these values and then use them as starting values for the parameters? if yes, then i gotta tell you that i can't do that either.

Comment: I used the Differential Evolution genetic algorithm to determine initial parameter estimates.